# Trying to read a json file into a Map[String,Object] in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to read out a json config file into my scala project. The format of the json is as follows:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "testInteger",
      "type": "Integer",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "name": "testString",
      "type": "String",
      "value": "yeah"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have been using spark to generate a data frame

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(path)
```

I am needing the data from the json file to then be read into a Map that has key "name" and value of the specified type

Expected Output:

```
Map: "testInteger" -> 10
     "testString" -> "yeah"
```

I am new to scala and unsure where to start, any advice would be appreciated.

(Note: using Java 8 and intellij to write)

Comment: Can you add your expected output ?

Comment: what do you want to do it after converting to `map`.

Comment: Ideally would like to be "testInteger" -> 10, "testString" -> "yeah"

Comment: I should clarify, there is potentially going to be more than one Map object. In this case the map would be called Parameters and would map a string (name) to the value of the specified type. I need to have the functionality to expand to include more maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is what you should do,

1. Create SparkSession,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, StructType}

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

2. Create Schema,

```
val schema = new StructType().add(
"parameters",ArrayType.apply(
      new StructType()
          .add("name", "string")
          .add("type", "string")
          .add("value", "string")
       ))
```

3. Read data set,

```
 val df = spark.read
      .option("multiline", "true")
      .schema(schema)
      .json("/path/to/json")
      .select(explode(col("parameters")).alias("params"))
```

This will give you a `struct` column called 'params' with fields `name`, `type` and `value`. This will look like,

```
root
 |-- params: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

**Note:** All `struct` and `map` type columns impose type safety. So the schema cannot allow values of a different type in the same column. Thus all your values in `value` field will be cast to `string`. As per your use case, you can use `udf` to cast things at runtime using the field `type`.